# JButton disappears when adding JTextrea

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm having an issue with my Java program where I can add a JButton to the panel in JFrame, but when I create an JTextArea object, the JButton disappears?

```
package sandBox;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello world");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,500);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button2 = new JButton("STOP");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("GO");
        JTextArea text1 = new JTextArea();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(button1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(button2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(panel);

    }

}
```

Comment: And how do you add JTextArea on panel?

Comment: Is this the complete code that you are trying? call `frame.setVisible(true);` in the end after adding all the components.

Comment: Are you saying that just by _initializing_ a TextArea the buttons dissapear? Or is your code incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember

1. `BorderLayout` will only allow a single component to occupy each of the available positions. Adding another component will cover the previous component
2. Where possible, always call `setVisible` after you've created the UI
3. To actually add all your components, your example doesn't actually add the `JTextArea` to the container

Someone like...

```
//...
// frame.setVisible(true);
//...

frame.add(text1);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Might help

Comment: Sorry but OP is using correct properties of `BorderLayout` while adding the component.

Comment: Yes well this is the problem, if I comment out the textarea object creator and run the program, my buttons show, where as if I remove the comment, the buttons don't show.

Comment: @ElliottCoe very interesting problem.

Comment: @ElliottCoe Try two things. 1- try resizing the frame, see if the buttons become visible. 2- Call setVisible last

Comment: @braj To be honest, I don't trust the OPs code, as the text area isn't even been added to the screen, but is suggested as the course of the problem, either the code is wrong or the description is wrong. The tip is still valid and is used to cover my back side ;)

Comment: Aha! calling setVisable last made everything show up how it should! does anyone have an explanation as to why it does this?

Comment: It has to do with the way the layout managers are notified of changes to the container hierarchy. Calling setVisible forces the frame to revalidate it's entire contents, making sure all the containers are notified and laid out. Unfortunately, simply adding components to the frame doesn't seem to perform the same task, you would need to call revalidate manually

Comment: Nothing no question at all :)

Comment: One other trick when components don't seem to appear is to simpy resize the main frame, causing the containers to invalidate and relaid out. At least ts way you know if they've been added or not and diagnose the problem from there ;)